# Framework for Edit SQL Tables Automatically

Tags: java, sql

Is there a framework or something that i say to it which the table is, and it automatically shows all rows and let me edit the fields?

Something like php my admin i imagine, that i can implement in my java application.

Thanks!

Comment: Try Googling for "java sql  table editor framework" or something like that.  There are hits that could possibly be solutions ... but it depends on what precisely you need, and how much work your are prepared to invest in integration, re-factoring etcetera.

Comment: This is borderline off-topic and "too broad"